# How to add an "apply for a job" button to a content type?

Tags: 7, ajax, nodes

I am trying to add an apply button to a content type, like job, so when the user visit the content he could click "apply button", and his resume will be send automatically to the author of the content.

I would prefer this be achieved with AJAX. How can I make something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do that using [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module, create a flag named 'Apply' and set it for job content types. You can then use Flag Actions or [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) to send emails.

Comment: Good if there is not a lot data needed to apply. If only thing needed is "who applied" and maybe one text field, it's better than webform as it's easier to set up. If there are more fields needed to apply, like available hours or some other data specific not to user but to applying itself, flag will be lacking functionality. That said, +1 from me of course ;)

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, the flag module was the easiest way to do it. But what if i had a Resume field on the user's profile and by clicking "apply button" the users resume file would be send automatically, is something like this possible ?

Comment: @Jimbo of course, with Rules. Flag triggers rules, and in rules you can set up mail sending. You have tokens for the content flagged (including it's author) and for the person who flagged. Try to set this up in test environment, and when you'll have basic knowledge, come back to us and ask more detailed questions. Or not, if you will find Rules easy enough :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the apply button on the node detail page then you can make use of ctools link to get this functionality done.

All you have to do is implement a ctools menu item and a callback that will do the processing to send the users resume to the author of the node(job).

Then in the template file for the node you can add a ctools link by using the ctools_ajax_text_button() function of the ctools module.

For more details on how to imeplement this functionality. Please download and enable the ctools module. It has got a very good example module that will give you a clear idea on how to implement a the functionality you are looking for..

Answer (score 2):

Your situation looks like a case for a [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module - it provides GUI and allows you to design apply forms without any coding. If you will add [Webform steps](https://drupal.org/project/webform_steps) or similar helper, you will be able to make your article a first "step", and actual applying for a job a second one.